# Import Feeds module & Tamper in combination with atypical csv file

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting

I'm trying to do an import from a csv file using [Feed Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/feed_import) & [Feeds Tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) modules. I'm in a bit over my head though. The feed I need to import uses an atypical format. Instead of having a traditional header attached to each column, the header content is pertinent to each content imported. For instance the header will contain content specific to each row from my csv. I'm trying to avoid modifying the content each time before I import it if possible. Does anyone have any suggestions how I can get the header content added to each specific row of content from the csv? CSV content is as follows.

```
(row 1)  A     JC   2450    5/11/2015   5021
(row 2) C2111   3   327     340 
(row 3) C2111   4   330     345 
(row 4) C2111   5   338     332.5   
(row 5) C2111   7   392     315
```